# Pandas group by multiple columns and get output in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a scenario where I have a dataframe like:

dF:

```
         a  b  c  d  e  kmeans
counter 
0        1  1  1  1  1   1
1        0  0  1  0  1   2
2        1  0  1  1  1   3
3        0  1  0  0  0   1
4        0  0  0  1  0   2
5        1  1  0  0  1   2
```

and the output i want is:

```
   1   2   3
a  1   1   0
b  2   1   0
c  1   1   1
d  1   1   1
e  1   2   1
```

I have something like *500+* columns in my original dataframe and i want them to groupby by those columns and get them as rows and transpose last column row values into columns.

I am trying to group by like:

`df.groupby(col[0:-1])['kmeans'].sum() but i get an error`

I have used `groupby`'s before but never faced a problem like this.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why is `(a,1) == 2`? Looks like it should be `1`

Comment: my bad! i edited my question. apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need aggregate `sum` by `kmeans`, then transpose and last remove column name `kmeans`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('kmeans').sum().T.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
   1  2  3
a  1  1  1
b  2  1  0
c  1  1  1
d  1  1  1
e  1  2  1
```

Or if create index by `kmeans` then use only `sum` by first level, transpose and last remove column mame:

```
df1 = df.set_index('kmeans').sum(level=0).T.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
   1  2  3
a  1  1  1
b  2  1  0
c  1  1  1
d  1  1  1
e  1  2  1
```

Comment: woah! i got the answer
let me check if it's working on my case. Thanks a lot!!!!